# What is the origin of chirality in the universe?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am just curious with the fact that our body is made of so many chiral molecules the DNA that we possess is chiral, the amino acids in our body is chiral and there are many other objects other than the molecules which show chirality. So,I want to know what is the origin of chirality in the universe.

Comment: For all we know, it is just a coincidence.

Comment: Perhaps a distinction should be made. The reason why there *are* chiral molecules in the first place is that some atoms (notably, carbon) can have stable asymmetric substitution, I'd say. So it's really a fundamental physical property of matter; I'm not sure things could work any other way; maybe some physics experts know. Then the fact that most amino acids making up the proteins in the human body have *one* specific configuration (S) rather than the opposite one (R) is indeed probably just a coincidence. Very interesting question though.

Comment: First consider the comment of @user6376297. Lots of molecules must be chiral by existence! For why in leaving kingdom there is a large excess of one form: digging the web you find scientific hypothesis, of which I link an example https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/01/110107145634.htm

Comment: Interesting article! Reading the conclusion *"These findings imply that the selection of a single enantiomer for the molecules of life observed on Earth is not the result of chance but rather of a deterministic physical mechanism."* one may then ask the next question: why was there an excess of one enantiomeric form in the place where these extraterrestrial molecules originated? So yes, no problem hypothesizing that what happened *on Earth* was mechanistic. Different story would be to imply that there was some form of 'choice' at the very origin of matter. Quite a delicate topic.

Comment: IT is a big question with a lot of uncertainty about the true answer. But one chemical phenomenon is important whatever the mechanism and that is the ability of certain reactions to increase small differences in the ratio of chiral enantiomers by self-catalytic reactions. In short: start with a small excess and end up with a large one. What caused the initial imbalance could be chance or the result of a small chiral imbalance caused by some nuclear processes some of which are not symmetric in reflection.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about chemistry.

Comment: That's pretty much as asking why things can be asymmetrical. Nothing to do with chemistry,  more like philosophy and even that may be a stretch.

Comment: But the above mentioned article shows that it is a deterministic physical mechanism.

Comment: @Mithoron This question can be understood in two ways. One the one you voted to close for (Why can molecules be chiral in the first place) and one that Ivan commented on (Why are the molecules in our body of one specific enantiomer). Sadly, both are not answerable …

Comment: Thus is surely chemistry tough the question looks bombastic. Again the question is not why optically active molecules exist (legit itself) but why there is an asymmetry of enantiomers distribution in living kingdom. There is not an accepted answer: to the best of my knowledge this is ongoing research in chemistry / biochemistry and perhaps we will find out. It might be in principle even due to merely physical mechanisms. I am not sure that a Q is off topic just because we didn't know the answer. Also not sure this comment shall be an answer. But OP should have got it.

Comment: So, is there any current update about this research?